# How would you replicate this graphic in R

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I'm wondering how to do this graph in R?

[image: graph]

I tought about using geom_bar from the ggplot package. However I don't know how to plot the changing thickness and the colors that reflect the growth for the years at the same time.

I'd appreciate any ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: You could do it without the white space between layers using `geom_rect`. If you want answers with code in them (i.e., more specific than "try geom_rect"), you'd do well to share some sample data. Ideally an illustrative subset with maybe 4 years and 2 or 3 sectors, shared with `dput`.

Comment: I can honestly say that is a terrible graph. In an attempt to show everything on one graph, they've obscured most useful comparisons.

Comment: An interesting piece of art, though

Comment: I agree with @thelatemail - my eyes hurt just looking at it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some steps to start. Nothing special, just some rectangles. There is a lot of information going on in this chart, most of it is in the text along the sides, usually meaning that the chart isnt very effective.

The only useful info the chart really shows is the yearly change in colors. You can do something like that below where I colored based on the rectangle height.

But +1 for finding another way to visualize your data.

[image]

```
set.seed(1)
nr <- 4
nc <- 50
mm <- matrix(sort(runif(nr * nc)) * 10, nr, nc)
nn <- matrix(sort(runif(nr * nc), decreasing = TRUE) * 10, nr, nc)
mm <- do.call('rbind', l <- list(mm, nn))[order(sequence(sapply(l, nrow))), ]

yy <- 50
mm <- rbind(mm, yy - colSums(mm))
nr <- nrow(mm)

plot(0:nc, type = 'n', ylim = c(0, yy), bty = 'n', axes = FALSE, ann = FALSE)
rect(s <- sequence(nc), 0, s + .95, mm[1, ], border = NA,
     col = as.numeric(cut(mm[1, ], breaks = seq(0, 15, 3))))
axis(1, s + .5, labels = s + 2000, lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = 1)
axis(1, s, labels = NA, lwd = 0, lwd.ticks = .5, tcl = -.2)
# axis(2, las = 1, lwd = 0)
mtext('Share of private jobs', side = 2, at = par('usr')[3], adj = 0)
arrows(.5, 0, .5, yy, lwd = 2, xpd = NA, length = .1)
text(par('usr')[1:2] + c(.5, -.5), yy, labels = range(s) + 2000,
     xpd = NA, pos = 3, adj = 0)

yy <- matrix(0, 1, nc)
for (ii in 2:nr) {
  yy <- colSums(rbind(yy, mm[ii - 1, ]))
  rect(s, yy  + 1, s + .95, yy + mm[ii, ], border = NA, 
       col = as.numeric(cut(mm[ii, ], breaks = seq(0, 15, 3))))
}
```

(I hope no one submits this to junk charts :{ )

Also here is another incredibly simple way. Should have done this first, ie, create sample data, pad the rows, and let `barplot` take care of the rest. A lot less control over this approach, though.

```
mm <- matrix(sort(runif(10)), 2) * 10
nn <- matrix(.5, 2, ncol(mm))
mm <- do.call('rbind', l <- list(mm, nn))[order(sequence(sapply(l, nrow))), ]
yy <- 22
mm <- rbind(mm, yy - colSums(mm))
barplot(mm, col = 1:0, border = NA, axes = FALSE)
```

[image]